# how to get a welcome message in aws lex chat bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am creating a chatbot using amazon lex.
There is a use case for which I have to display a welcome message like 'Hello my name is LexC. How can i help you?'
How can I implement this? This message should be displayed without user type anything, so basically without invoking any intent.

Comment: Where is this chat bot going to be used? The answer will depend on that because Lex itself does not support this.

Comment: Its going to be used in Slack channel for now later it might be scale up to website or mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying it to do with Facebook Page, Then you can do this by following steps:

---

You can create a customized greeting from your Page that will appear in Facebook messages and in the Messenger app for iPhone, iPad and Android when someone begins a conversation with your Page for the first time. Your Page's greeting will appear before any messages are sent.

To create a Messenger greeting:

1. Click Settings at the top of your Page.
2. Click Messaging in the left column.
3. Next to Show a Messenger greeting, click to select On.
4. Click Change, edit the greeting, then click Save.

Answer (score 0):

Your Lex bot cannot display a "welcome" message without any prompts from the user. You would have to implement this functionality on the client side where the bot is integrated.

Since you mention that you're using the bot inside your web/mobile app, you can implement your own code to simply show a message to the user once your chat UI loads up in the app. For Slack however, you would have to look into their docs to see if something like that can be configured.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions

Comment: I am integrating my bot with the Facebook page. Any idea or suggestions how can I do that?